# How to convert BigInt to Number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bigint, ecma262

I found myself in the situation where I wanted to convert a `BigInt` value to a `Number` value. Knowing that my value is a [safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger), how can I convert it?

Comment: Are you referring to the Stage 3 proposal? That would be [documented there](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint#interoperation-with-number-and-string).

Comment: Nice @Xufox, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Turns out it's as easy as passing it to the `Number` constructor:

```
const myBigInt = BigInt(10);  // `10n` also works
const myNumber = Number(myBigInt);
```

Of course, you should bear in mind that your BigInt value must be within [[Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_SAFE_INTEGER), [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)] for the conversion to work properly, as stated in the question.

Comment: I wonder why `+myBigInt` is not supported yet.

Comment: @Mohammad see: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#dont-break-asmjs

Answer (score 30):

You can use `parseInt` or `Number`

```js
const large =  BigInt(309);
const b = parseInt(large);
console.log(b);
const n = Number(large);
console.log(n);
```

Comment: For performance reasons, I suggest not using `parseInt` for this. Yes, yes, according to the specs, both `parseInt` and `Number` ought to perform the conversion by converting the BigInt to a string before to a number. Nevertheless, the semantics of `parseInt` compared to the semantics of `Number` especially in view of how `BigInt(number)` yields a BigInt makes it more likely that browser vendors will apply more optimizations to `Number(bigValue)` than `parseInt(bigValue)` such that the stringification is internally skipped. Thus, I suggest using `Number` instead of `parseInt` for performance.

Comment: @JackGiffin please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/what-is-the-difference-between-parseint-and-number where `parseInt`  can be  better in some cases

Comment: I am afraid that I do not understand. I agree that `parseInt` and `Number` have different behaviors, but, for the purposes of converting a BigInt to a number, I can think of no cases where they would differ. Perhaps you could provide an example of where `Number` and `parseInt` differ in conversion of BigInts to numbers to enlighten me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JackGiffin   You are totally right in this case of `BigInts` and what I need to show is that `parseInt` and `Number` have different behaviors and you can see the example in the link above.

Comment: @I_Al-thamary: best practice is to use radix while using `parseInt`

Comment: if the BigInt value is too large to be represented as a Number, the conversion will result in a loss of precision or may even return NaN, and parseInt will lead to TypeError  `const tooBigIntValue = BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) + BigInt(1);
const convertedValue = Number(tooBigIntValue);
console.log(tooBigIntValue); // 9007199254740993n
console.log(convertedValue); // NaN
const convertedValue_parseInt = parseInt(tooBigIntValue)+ BigInt(1);
console.log(convertedValue_parseInt); // TypeError`

Answer (score 2):

### Avoiding Caveats

I know the scope of the original question is knowing you already have a "safe integer", but I wanted to give scope to others that land here how they should try to handle it.

#### `Number.isSafeInteger`

One would think you could utilize `Number.isSafeInteger`, but something trivial like the following snippet will show that utilizing the function on a `BigInt` will always be `false` even if the value is within the minimum and maximum bounds of a `Number`.

```js
console.log(Number.isSafeInteger(BigInt(1)))
// Returns false
```

### An Implementation using Results

This utilizes the TS-Results library to return a success or error response, rather than doing something like throwing.

If you do not want to use the Results library, you could instead return the value and throw otherwise, or handle it however you see appropriate.

```js
import { Err, Ok, Result } from 'ts-results'

export function bigIntToNumber(value: bigint): Result<number, Error> {
  if (validInterger(value)) {
    return Ok(Number(value))
  }

  return Err(new Error(`Value: "${value}" is out of bounds to be a Number`))
}

function validInteger(value: bigint): boolean {
  return value <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER && value >= Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
}
```

#### An Aside on Data Types and Data Ranges

Something interesting to note is that a JS number go up to `9,007,199,254,740,991` (the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`) while your classic 4-byte integer would only be `2,147,483,647`, thus a JS Number can hold more, but not as much as an 8-byte integer which goes up to
`9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

As noted in comments there can be numbers past `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` up to `Number.MAX_VALUE` that are still technically valid JS Numbers.
You can read more here:

- [Whats the difference between JS Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER and MAX_VALUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34799226)

Comment: Your last paragraph, as currently phrased, is incorrect. For example, `10_000_000_000_000_000_000` is totally a valid JS number. I know what you mean (`2**53 - 1` is between `2**31 - 1` and `2**63 - 1`, sure!), but that's not what that paragraph is currently saying. Another way of putting it: `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` != `Number.MAX_VALUE`. You're talking about the former, but JS numbers "go up to" (or "can hold" up to) the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: see the discussion in the comments below as to why this answer is **not** correct. I am leaving the answer up regardless for disambiguation.

You should use either of the static methods:

`BigInt.asIntN()` - Clamps a BigInt value to a signed integer value, and returns that value.
`BigInt.asUintN()` - Clamps a BigInt value to an unsigned integer value, and returns that value.

as documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#static_methods

Comment: @zr0gravity7 @naveen, I had the chance to test this and these methods do not return numbers, but BigInt values instead. Their names are misleading, as the `N` suggests `Number`, when in fact they still return BigInt values. Try running `typeof BigInt.asIntN(64, 1n)` to see that it reports `bigint`. So this answer actually does not answer the question.

Comment: True that. A confusing name. Was reading the documentation. <3

Comment: The explanation of the name is that "intN" is the generalization of "int32", "int64", "int555" and so on; or put differently: "intN" is short for "N-bit integer". The value of this N is the first parameter to the function. An alternative spec could have provided `BigInt.asInt64(x)` and `BigInt.asInt32(x)`, but for maximum flexibility the decision was made to have a single `BigInt.asIntN(N, x)` instead.

Comment: `as(Ui|I)ntN` does not do what you claim nor does this answer OP's question. These functions take a BigInt and return a BigInt modulo 2^N.