# How does javascript represent integers greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER internally?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, numbers are represented internally as double-precision floats, meaning there are 53 bits available to represent integer values. There's a `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant that illustrates this, which is equal to `Math.pow(2, 53) - 1`. However, in the javascript console, I can type `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 20` and it will spit out the correct integer value.

How does javascript represent numbers greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` internally?

Comment: I don't get it, you just answered your own question?

Comment: Try `+ 19` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34799443/3684265

Comment: I think the important thing here is the word **`SAFE`**

Comment: I understand that using numbers greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` isn't safe, so perhaps the better question would be *why* isn't it safe? Is it unsafe because some browsers will coerce to BigInt while others won't (inconsistent implementations)? Or because it will give unreliable results. Based on the comments and the answer now posted, it appears to be the latter.

Comment: Yes, unreliable results. Not all integers larger than the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER value can be *accurately* represented in 64-bit floating point, and will be subject to rounding.

Comment: @w.brian well, they will be represented reliably wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically floating point numbers are represented as:

```
 digits * 2 ** movement
```

`digits` has 52 bits, `movement` has 11 bits, and both together form a 64bit number (with 1 sign bit). Now integers can just be represented with `movement` being `0`, then `digits` contains the 52 bit number, and that can hold up to `2 ** 53 - 1` numbers. Now for larger numbers, you have to use `movement`, which basically means that you move the `digits` left or right, and therefore you lose accuracy.

Imagine digits would just take 8 bits

```
  number     >     digits | movement > result
   // savely represented
  11111111   >  111111111 | 0        > 11111111
  // lost the last 1
  111111111  >  111111111 | 1        > 111111110
   // lost the two last 1s
  1111111111 >  11111111  | 10       > 1111111100
```