# Incrementing MAX_SAFE_INTEGER in Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

How can this be explained that I get a result that ends in 92 for the first two calculations, and 94 for the third one?

```js
    console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1); //...92
    console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2); //...92
    console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 3); //...94
```

Comment: Weird, I get 9007199254740992, 9007199254740992 and 9007199254740994 in Chrome

Comment: Numbers beyond `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` cannot be represented accurately and are rounded which leads to mathematical errors. See: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmeti](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799226/whats-the-difference-between-js-number-max-safe-integer-and-max-value) `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is the largest integer in your safe calculation and any number larger than that is not safe.

**Edit**

For larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` use `BigInt` such as:

```
BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) + BigInt(2)
```

```js
 alert(BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) + BigInt(1)); //9007199254740992n
 alert(BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) + BigInt(2)); //9007199254740993n
 alert(BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) + BigInt(3)); //9007199254740994n
```